# Validate if input already exist in database ASP .NET Core 2.2

Tags: javascript, c#, onclick, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a form with some input fields and when you click on Save, I do a check if a field already exist in the database. I have a service method for this.

For example in the database the field with value "Test10" already exist and if the user use "Test10" in the input field and clicks on save I want to show this message :

[image]

```
private async Task<bool> CheckIfCodeAlreadyExist(string code)
{
    return await _service.CheckCodeExist(code);
}
```

I tried with session vaiables, with an extra bool parameter but not effective enough.
My JavaScript knowlegde is not that much, but would it possible to check this with a "onClick" event in the form?

If the result is true you stay on the page with the message.

[image]

Don't mind the Model.Code is red.

Comment: You can have your button submit an AJAX call to check and if it comes back good then you can continue to submit the form. You'd also want to verify it again in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it with onClick if you have liberty to use `Remote` validation .net MVC offers.

Decorate you model property with something like:
`[Remote("Action", "Controller", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Code")]` 
Or pass additional fields as well:
`[Remote("Action", "Controller", AdditionalFields = "Id", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Code")]`

with javascript and jquery, you do ajax request.

Bind click event to button:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
     url: '/Controller/Action',
     method: 'get',
     data: {
        code: $('#Code').val()
     }
   }).done(function (result) {
      if (result) {
         // code valid
         $('form').submit();
      } else {
         // show error
      }
   }).fail(function () {
        // ajax request failed
   });
});
```

Controller/Action to return bool:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckIfCodeAlreadyExist(string code)
{
    return await _service.CheckCodeExist(code);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I tried with Remote Validation but can't get it to work.

Comment: @user11208424 where do you find issue? can you update your question with what you've tried so far with remote validation? That way its easy to find out the issue. Remote validations fire at keydown event once it activated by change event on input.

Comment: I got the error message : InvalidOperationException: No URL for remote validation could be found.

Comment: how does the action method look like? its hard to say without looking at the full code for remote validation i.e. model property with remote attribute, controller action method.

Comment: @user11208424 check this: https://forums.asp.net/t/2151403.aspx

Comment: Oh dear, I tried the things I found and as you suggested but can't get it to work, updated my question with what I want. I don't know what to do with the Json response where it goes?

Comment: @user11208424 i can feel that. have you tried ajax using jquery? where are you trying to handle json response? it is better to post your updated code where its either partially or completely not working, so others can help with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Microsoft's documentation for model validation, specifically remote validation. The use case and example for this is almost identical to yours:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#remote-attribute-1

> The `[Remote]` attribute implements client-side validation that requires
> calling a method on the server to determine whether field input is
> valid. For example, the app may need to verify whether a user name is
> already in use.

In your case, you may use a model with a `Code` property like this one:

```
[Remote(action: "CheckCode", controller: "Home")]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

On the server under the corresponding controller, you can provide the endpoint needed to validate the code:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public IActionResult CheckCode(string code)
{
    if (!yourService.VerifyCode(code))
    {
        return Json($"Code {code} is already in use.");
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```